# Add Refresh Button to Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi everyone Im having a pain in the ass time trying to get this Navigation bar to include a Refresh Button if you can look at the code below and then provide some help this is my original code along with the UIBarbutton snippet that i found for the refresh button from another users project on google. Which i am running into the following errors:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [ColorHelper charcoalBackgroundImage];
    UIBarButtonItem *refresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refresh;
    // [button release]; remove this line if you're using ARC
}
- (void) refresh
{

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: Where's the code where you try to add the refresh button?

Comment: Please edit your question to include this code (showing what method it's inside of). Code in a comment is hard to read.

Comment: Just edited that sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Your edit is not correct -- that wouldn't even compile. Is that new code supposed to be inside the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: From the example I found I took that code snippet, placed it in the viewdidload as the previous example i found had but ran into the same issue. Which was why i posted that here. I don't know if its the code snippet or if its the placement and location of the code thats incorrect.

Comment: You should post what you actually tried. What you're showing won't even compile. The code you show should work fine if it's in viewDidLoad, assuming that your controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Posted along with errors from Xcode

Comment: Put the code inside viewDidLoad, and delete the [button release] line.

Comment: Thank you that did work but it now closes out of the app on selection of the refresh button.

Comment: Did you implement the refresh: method? If not, it will crash

Comment: Where would this refresh method need to be implemented?

Comment: Anywhere in that same controller.

Comment: I apologize would you assist or show me an example that i can look at to build this method for the navigation button that you helped me to place inside that viewdidload?

Comment: I placed what i thought would be correct but it is still closing upon clicking the button and no errors or code issues are showing present when i run or test

Comment: That's because the method is refresh: (with a colon), not refresh as you put in your code.

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [ColorHelper charcoalBackgroundImage];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
}
```

Write your method as this because you are passing UIBarButton object in call.

```
- (void) refresh:(id)sender
{

}
```

**OR**

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh)];
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this code will help you...

```
UIImage *reloadImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reload.png"];
UIButton *btnReload = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnReload.bounds = CGRectMake( 10, 0, reloadImage.size.width, reloadImage.size.height );
[btnReload addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnReload setImage:reloadImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *reloadButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnReload];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = reloadButton;
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, this actually removes a refresh button all together when placed in my code. Is this supposed to be in conjunction with the existing code or solely used for that refresh button? I tried a variation of both with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [ColorHelper charcoalBackgroundImage];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
    // [button release]; remove this line if you're using ARC
}
```

It seems that you are already use ARC. So you should remove `[button release]`. Your book is on the way to the history.

Answer (score 0):

Your action selector and the actual method are not the same. One is `refresh:` and the other is `refresh`.

Change the selector to match the actual method.

```
@selector(refresh)
```

Comment: I changed the @selector(refresh) and ran into the same issue where the app closes upon selection of the refresh button.

Comment: try clean your  build and reset the simulator .

Answer (score 0):

for swift 4

```
let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(refresh))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton

@objc func refresh() {

}
```